# android.net.SIP (Session Initiation Protocol) registration error -4 (-5) on Turkish locale

Tags: java, android, sip, registration

The problem lies in sip calls in the Turkish locale.

If the current locale is Turkish on the device, any sip registration, for any work domain, ends with a registration error of -4 (only on Xiaomi Mi MIX2 error -5).

And, most interestingly, on any other locale (tested on the RU, PL, PT, FR, DE) sip works fine, without any errors.

This problem is found on absolutely all Android devices (in the Turkish locale) except Samsung S8 and Samsung S9.

As a solution to the problem, the replacement of the locale in the configuration was tested for one of the working locales, but no changes occurred - the registration ends with the above error.

In android.sip, we pass our context, respectively, the thought arose of seeing what we take from the contest and replace it with the data of the working locale, but all that the sip takes from
context is packageName and in all locales this name is identical and correct.

I use the official implementation of android.sip. I throw off only the registration code, since With successful registration, calls work normally:

```
private final SipRegistrationListener callIfReadyListener = new SipRegistrationListener () {
        public void onRegistering (String localProfileUri) {
            Log.d (TAG, "Registering with SIP Server ...");
        }

        public void onRegistrationDone (String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) 
        {
            Log.d (TAG, "Ready");
            if (! cancel)
                handler.post (new Runnable () {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        startCall ();
                    }
                });
        }

        public void onRegistrationFailed (String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                         String errorMessage) {
            Log.d (TAG, "Registration failed. Please check settings.");
            Log.d (TAG, "Registration failed with errorCode" \ n "errorMessage");
            if (errorCode! = SipErrorCode.IN_PROGRESS) {
                retryCall ();
            }
        }
    };

SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder (username, domain);
String displayName = repository.getPrefix () + "_Android_" + String.valueOf (repository.getUserId());
builder.setDisplayName(displayName);
builder.setPassword(password);
me = builder.build();

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast (context, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
manager.open(me, pi, null);
manager.register(me, 30, callIfReadyListener);

Logs with an error:
I / PermissionHelper: PERMISSION: Permission Granted
D / SipPresenter: Initialize Profile
Android_displayname
Registering with SIP Server ...
Registration failed. Please check settings.
Registration failed with -4
    registration timed out
retry calling
Initialize profile
Android_displayname
Registering with SIP Server ...
Registration failed. Please check settings.
Registration failed with -4

Work Logs:
PERMISSION: Permission Granted
D / SipPresenter: Initialize Profile
D / SipPresenter: Android_displayname
W / System.err: android.net.sip.SipException: SipService.createSession() returns null
W / System.err: at android.net.sip.SipManager.register(SipManager.java e13)
W / System.err: SipPresenter.initializeLocalProfile(SipPresenter.java:150)
W / System.err: SipPresenter.initializeManager SipPresenter.java:120)
W / System.err: SipPresenter $ 5.run (SipPresenter.java:214)
D / SipPresenter: retry calling
D / SipPresenter: Connection Error.
D / SipPresenter: Initialize Profile
D / SipPresenter: Android_displayname
D / SipPresenter: Registering with SIP Server ...
D / SipPresenter: Ready
D / SipPresenter: sip: name__token @ domain
D / SipPresenter: TR @ domain
D / SipPresenter: android.net.sip.SipAudioCall@3a08306
D / SipPresenter: call established
D / AudioGroup: stream [96] is configured as GSM 8kHz 20ms mode 0
D / AudioGroup: stream [114] is configured as RAW 8kHz 32ms mode 0
D / AudioGroup: stream [114] joins group [113]
D / AudioGroup: stream [96] joins group [113]
D / AudioGroup: group [113] switches from mode 0 to 2
D / AudioGroup: reported frame count: output 328, input 320
D / AudioGroup: adjusted frame count: output 512, input 512
D / AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 170 for frameCount 512
D / AudioGroup: latency: output 112, input 64
D / AudioGroup: stream [96] leaves group [113]
D / AudioGroup: stream [96] is dead
D / AudioTrack: stop() called with 16384 frames delivered
D / AudioGroup: stream [114] is dead
D / AudioGroup: group [113] is dead
```

Also, the calls were tested on another library: org.pjsip.pjsua2, everything worked correctly in the Turkish locale. There are suggestions that the problem is poorly optimized Android on a variety of devices
except Samsung, even though the library takes from the context only the packageName, but in depth uses the android.os functionality.

I ask for help in this matter, what settings or crutches for the sip can be introduced to work in the Turkish locale. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I advise you to compare the exact content of username, domain and password for both locale. May be you already did. (does the password contains UTF8 char not available in ASCII?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggested options. I once again made sure that these data are completely identical in all locales. Password contains only ASCII characters.